# How to find/remove file associations for a certain program in KDE

Tags: kde, file-opening

I had a program installed on my Kubuntu system that was able to open a lot of different graphics file types and registered as default program for many of those file types. I have unistalled the program, but in the file associations it is still present and every now and then as I try to open a file from the file manager, it tries to launch the no longer existing program.

I could remove that association for the most often used file types via the file associations dialogue in KDE's settings menu. Unfortunately, in this dialog I can only search for a file type and see/edit the associated programs, but in this case, I would need to search for the program and see all file types that it is associated to.

Is there a way to achieve this? If not via the settings, maybe in some config file, where I can just remove all hints to that program?

Comment: Most likely it is in the mimeapps.list, see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/default_applications for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KDE uses [freedesktop.org's standard `mimeapps.list` files](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/mime-apps-spec/mime-apps-spec-1.0.1.html) for associating MIME types (file types) to applications.

> The lookup order for this file is as follows:
>
> - `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/$desktop-mimeapps.list`
>
>   - user overrides, desktop-specific (for advanced users)
> - `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/mimeapps.list`
>
>   - user overrides (recommended location for user configuration GUIs)
> - `$XDG_CONFIG_DIRS/$desktop-mimeapps.list`
>
>   - sysadmin and ISV overrides, desktop-specific
> - `$XDG_CONFIG_DIRS/mimeapps.list`
>
>   - sysadmin and ISV overrides
> - `$XDG_DATA_HOME/applications/$desktop-mimeapps.list`
>
>   - for completeness, deprecated, desktop-specific
> - `$XDG_DATA_HOME/applications/mimeapps.list`
>
>   - for compatibility, deprecated
> - `$XDG_DATA_DIRS/applications/$desktop-mimeapps.list`
>
>   - distribution-provided defaults, desktop-specific
> - `$XDG_DATA_DIRS/applications/mimeapps.list`
>
>   - distribution-provided defaults
>
> In this table, $desktop is one of the names of the current desktop, lowercase (for instance, kde, gnome, xfce, etc.)
>
> This is determined from taking the ascii-lowercase form of a component the environment variable $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP, which is a colon-separated list of names that the current desktop is known as.

[Note that](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html):

> `$XDG_DATA_HOME` defines the base directory relative to which user specific data files should be stored. If `$XDG_DATA_HOME` is either not set or empty, a default equal to `$HOME/.local/share` should be used.
>
> `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` defines the base directory relative to which user specific configuration files should be stored. If `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is either not set or empty, a default equal to `$HOME/.config` should be used.

These are plaintext, [ini-style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file) files that can be searched for a program of interest.